# Laravel many to many relationship, add more objects into "pivot"?

Tags: php, laravel, pivot

Usually a many to many relationship will return something like this:

`Product::with('brands')->find(4);`

```
{
  id: 4
  name: 
  price:
  brands: [
    id: 6
    pivot: {
      product_id: 4,
      brand_id: 6,
      // withPivot fields goes here if specified.
      // I want to add extra fields here too, unrelated to the database. e.g. :
      foo: 'bar'
    }

  ],
  suppliers: [

  ]
}
```

This is done in `Product.php`:

```
public function brands()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Brand');
}
```

Do we have any control over what goes into the `pivot` object? I understand it spits out the two foreign key ids and whatever `withPivot` you've included but I want to add another property  but I'm unsure how to do it. Laravel does all this many-to-many stuff magically behind the scenes.

Doing something like this will give an error (I'm trying to add `foo: "bar"` to every pivot)

```
public function brands()
{
  $brands = $this->belongsToMany('Brand'); 

  foreach($brands as $brand)
  {
    $brand->foo = 'bar';
  }

  return $brands;
}
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to add? Normally adding it to the related model (`Brand` in this case) should be fine.

Comment: I've edited my post to clarify but I don't think I can make it simpler than that. This has nothing to do with `Brand`, its more to do with having control over the general json output.

Comment: I see. But is the value static or from where do you get it?

Comment: Static for now but I plan on adding dynamic values such as another result set e.g. `Supplier::find($brand->supplier_id)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are interested in modifying it JSON output you can override `toArray()` and add the property in there:

```
public function toArray(){
    foreach($this->brands as $brand){
        $brand->pivot->foo = 'bar';
    }
    return parent::toArray();
}
```

### Update

To avoid unwanted loading of the `brands` relation. You can first get the array and check if the relationship has been loaded

```
public function toArray(){
    $array = parent::toArray();
    if(isset($array['brands'])){
        foreach($array['brands'] as &$brand){
            $brand['pivot']['foo'] = 'bar';
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Note that I'm using `&` before `$brand` to pass the array in by reference and not only by value. Otherwise I would have to do `$array['brands'][$index]['pivot']['foo'] =` inside the loop.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This works fine for `Product` but if I call another model that has a many-to-many relationship with `Product`, it will always trigger `$this->brands` in your foreach loop, which is unwanted. This results in the product's brands always being displayed. I've tried doing `$hidden = ['brands'];` but I know this is wrong. Is there any way to fix this?